# Hide Columns in a DataGridView with a List<> as DataSource?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

I have a `List<>` of a `class X`.

`X` has 3 Columns: `a`, `b` and `c`.

Now I bind the List on the `DataGridView`:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = list;
```

How to only show Column a and `c` in the `GridView`, so hide Column `b`?

I will not edit the list itself, if possible, and not generate a new list, if possible.

Any solution here?

Answer (score 10):

I am assuming your class is like this:

```
private class MyClass
{
  [DisplayName("Foo/Bar")]
  public string FooBar { get; private set; }

  [Browsable(false)]
  public decimal Baz { get; private set; }

  [DisplayName("Baz")]
  public CurrencyBaz => string.Format(Baz, "C2");
}
```

In the above code the gridview column names are like this

- column name1: `("Foo/Bar")`
- column name2: `"Baz"`
- column name3: `"CurrencyBaz"`

**if you dont want to show the column you can just add this attribute:** `[Browsable(false)]`

In the above code column name 2 is not displayed ......

I hope it will helps you...

Comment: soooo great, thanks. didn't know about this Attribute!

Answer (score 6):

Hiding the columns will work but can make the DataGridView more difficult to work with.  I think you are better off not to add the columns at all.  To accomplish this I like to create an interface for my object that only exposes the fields I want visible in my DataGridView then bind to the interface instead of the object.

```
public interface IMyBindingObject
{
    string A { get; set; }
    string C { get; set; }
}


public class MyObject : IMyBindingObject
{
    public MyObject(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<IMyBindingObject> obj = new List<IMyBindingObject>();
    obj.Add(new MyObject("Test A", "Test B", "Test C"));
    obj.Add(new MyObject("T A", "T B", "T C"));

    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to:

```
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Then you will need to add a column for each of the class X's members and databind those.

Answer (score 1):

Or hide columns by name

```
dgvEmployees.DataSource = data
dgvEmployees.Columns("Id").Visible = False
dgvEmployees.Columns("ElementEtat").Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

the basic stuffs you need to do this,

first set AutoGenerateColumns property to False

```
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

After that in RowDataBound Event you do like this

```
protected void dataGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.Header)
            {

                e.Row.Cells[index of the cell to hide].Visible =false;

            }
        }
```